# Rails API using devise auth_token logs out logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, devise, token

So here's the scenario:

User can login normally through devise login. Once logged in, the user dashboard has embedded flash which makes calls to api on same server (both at localhost:3000 currently).

Calls to API are made with a supplied auth_token, using devise's token_authenticatable.

Here's there the problem occurs.

Once an API request is made, the logged in user is logged out.

I've done a lot of digging around but haven't found any solid leads on how I might solve this.

I believe the problem is because the call to the API is overwriting the user's cookie which was set by the browser. I tested this by watching auth cookie being set and being overwritten once the API is called.

FYI I'm developing in Chrome.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If I haven't gone into enough details please let me know if I can provide any other information that might help you diagnose the issue.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not posting the CSRF token to your server. CSRF protection is on by default on all Rails application. You can bypass it by adding following line to your controller.

```
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. All makes sense now hah